# JPA -- Multiple ManyToMany Lists of the same type in one Entity

Tags: java, list, jpa, many-to-many

I have a class that contains two Lists. Both lists are of the same type. The relationship for both lists is many-to-many.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task_instance")
public class TaskInstance {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<ScriptExecutableOrder> preScriptExecutables;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<ScriptExecutableOrder> postScriptExecutables;
    ...
}
```

A join table is created automatically that looks like this:
[image: Join table for TaskInstance and ScriptExecutableOrder]

However, when I use the getter methods to retrieve the Lists (i.e., `getPreScriptExecutables()` and `getPostScriptExecutables()`), the Lists are out of order. Through debugging, I have determined this: when the Lists are set, the order is consistent. I can set the Lists and get them, and the order is as epxected. Yet, when the `EntityManager` is closed, apparently the order is confounded. When a new `EntityManager` is opened and the getter is used to retrieve the Lists, the objects are ordered by the ScriptExecutableOrders' ids. Opening a new `EntityManager` is when the order is lost completely, even though the MySQL table is still in the appropriate order.

I have also tried creating separate join tables using the `@JoinTable` annotation. However, this didn't solve the problem.

I assume that somehow the way that I am setting up the entities and tables is causing this discrepancy, but I cannot figure it out. I am completely new to JPA.

Comment: What order do you want them in? For the order to be prreserved when you save them to the database, there has to be some database ordering that defines that. The Entity Manager is going to use a `SELECT` to retrieve the list later, so what `ORDER BY` is it supposed to use? Once you save the data and close the Entity Manager, the only information about the Entities is stored in the database.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear I'm not writing a query. I'm just calling the `getPreScriptExecutables()` or `getPostScriptExecutables()` functions within the `TaskInstance` class, but the objects are no longer in the order the original order. An ArrayList should maintain the order, but for some reason the order is changed.

If I use the `EntityManager`, I use the `find()` function to retrieve the `TaskInstance` object that I'm looking for, and then I call the getters on that instance.

Comment: Yes, but once the ArrayList has been saved to the database and then garbage collected away, how does the database keep that original order? Without a field in the database to hold the sequence of the list the order **cannot** be preserved. It's a simple as that. How is the database going to 'remember' the original order of the ArrayList? You may not be writing a query, but the underlying Entity Manager will use a `SELECT` to retrieve your list from the database. Tell me how that `SELECT` will get the records back in the original order you had them in the ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I used the `@JoinTable` annotation for both `Lists` (`preScriptExecutables` and `postScriptExecutables`), and then I added the `@OrderColumn` annotation like this

```
@OrderColumn(name = "list_index")
```

for both `Lists`. This created a column that would serve for ordering purposes.